# When will our app appear in the search

Tags: facebook

We have submitted our app several times to search and it still doesn't appear in the search results.

The app is [Rugby Coach](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=142921735788293) with app id 142921735788293. It has been well over a week since submitting it to search.

Please let us know if there is anything we am missing here?

Thanks,
c8apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an application that took 2 weeks to process.  Unfortunately, they get a lot of applications submitted to the search and need to make sure that each one is suitable.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the feedback. However, this is not our first rodeo show. Back in the submitting to directory system, it only took a couple of days. This is over a week. Especially since we are paying for advertising the app on their system too.

Comment: If you're paying for advertising, you should escalate this with your account manager at facebook ASAP.

Comment: Good call snipe, submitted a ticket. But from our experience we have found action happens faster at FB if we make a public deal of it.

Comment: I have the same problem.  How do you "submit it to search"?  Is that something you have to do, manually?  From what I read, apps should be queued to be added to the search, automatically, once they have 10 monthly users.  The app will then be added when FB rebuilds their index, which can take 2-4 weeks.  That's what I've been waiting on for 3 weeks.  Did I miss a step?

Comment: I would try and be patient.  Facebook get lots of apps created on a daily basis.